# Azure graph API create B2C user with custom user attribute in Node JS

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Could you please help me to create a user in Azure AD B2C using node js client.

In that request, I need to populate "signInNames" and custom user attribute which I create for my application in B2c.

If you share a sample request is much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code uses the [Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node) and [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) packages to interact with [the Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog).

1) Acquire an access token for use with the Azure AD Graph API:

```
const AuthenticationContext = require("adal-node").AuthenticationContext;

const tenant = "myb2cdomain.onmicrosoft.com";
const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}`;

const authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

function acquireTokenForApplication(clientId, clientSecret, callback) {
    authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials("https://graph.windows.net/", clientId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        callback(null, tokenResponse.access_token);
    });
}
```

2) Create a user object:

```
const userToBeCreated = {
    accountEnabled: true,
    creationType: "LocalAccount",
    displayName: "Alex Wu",
    passwordPolicies: "DisablePasswordExpiration",
    passwordProfile: {
        forceChangePasswordNextLogin: false,
        password: "Test1234"
    },
    signInNames: [
        {
            type: "emailAddress",
            value: "alexw@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "extension_xxx_<customAttributeName>": <customAttributeValue>
};
```

where "xxx" must be replaced with the application identifier (without hyphens) for your `b2c-extensions-app` application.

E.g.:

```
"extension_ab603c56068041afb2f6832e2a17e237_SkypeId": "alexw.skype"
```

3) Send the user object to [the Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser):

```
function createUser(tenantId, accessToken, userToBeCreated, callback) {
    request.post({
        url: `https://graph.windows.net/${encodeURIComponent(tenantId)}/users?api-version=1.6`,
        auth: {
            bearer: accessToken
        },
        body: userToBeCreated,
        json: true
    }, (err, response, responseBody) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        if (!isSuccessStatusCode(response.statusCode)) {
            const errorResult = responseBody;

            callback({
                code: errorResult["odata.error"].code,
                message: errorResult["odata.error"].message.value
            });

            return;
        }

        const createdUser = responseBody;
        callback(null, createdUser);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris, can you give more clarity on which application identifier for the set in extension attribute

Comment: It is [the b2c-extensions-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-extensions-app) application that is created when the Azure AD B2C tenant is created.

Comment: I wish this was in azure samples or azure quickstart projects on github